# Using XPath, How do I get the text nodes that are not part of hyperlinks

Tags: xpath

I would like to get all the text nodes of a document, but only those that are NOT part of a hyperlink.

Test sample:

```
Hello <a class='foobar' href='foo.html'>foo</a>World Hello foo World
```

The result text nodes should include the text node with Hello foo World, but not the hyperlink.

I tried `"//*[not(@href)]/text()"` , but this does not appear to work.

**UPDATE**

As my answer below (hopefully) explains, my problem was that the query was looking for nodes inside the root node, but not the root node itself. My answer is below.

Andrew came up with a different approach that is probably more clear as to intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also exclude parents (which i think is what you were thinking of earlier?), but you need to place the exclusion later (and the shorthand notation doesn't seem to work in this context):

```
//text()[not(parent::a)]
```

for example:

```
> cat foo.xml 
<b>
<a href="href">baz</a>
text
<c>foo<a href="href">bar</a>here</c>
more
</b>

> xpath foo.xml "//text()[not(parent::a)]"
Found 5 nodes:
-- NODE --

-- NODE --

text
-- NODE --
foo-- NODE --
here-- NODE --

more
```

Comment: +1 for `xpath` util, which I did not know existed till this answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: it's in the "werken-xpath" package in opensuse and seems to come from http://sourceforge.net/projects/werken-xpath/ - to be honest i only used it because i couldn't get saxon working the way i wanted in a hurry and opensuse listed it as an alternative...

Answer (score 2):

OK, a light bulb popped on. I wanted text that was inside any node, including the root node. Correct answer is:

```
//*[not(@href)]/text() | /text()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//text()[not(ancestor::a)]
```

This selects any text node that *isn't a descendent* of an `a` element.